# Subset Dataframe Using Modulus Operator

Tags: pandas, modulus

Let's say I have a dataframe with a series that is a collection of random numbers from 1 to 100000.  Let's say I want to split the dataframe into to dataframes based on the modulues operator.

```
a = df[col] % 100 > 10
b = df[col] % 100 <= 10
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What is your question ? I think you already have the answer

Comment: the above syntax doesn't work....

Comment: never mind figured it out.

Comment: df[df[col] % 100 > 10] ?

Comment: that works haha